# Set up proxy for Java app deployed in tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy

I am deploying the application in a Tomcat 8.5 . This tomcat runs behind a proxy. If I use eclipse, the application runs properly, but not in Tomcat. I have seen that if I get authenticated using a web browser, the application runs ok while the authentication still remains. Once it is expired, I need to provide the credentials again.

I've tried to provide this information via code and have also added these lines to the catalina.bat:

http.proxyHost=proxy.myproxy.es

http.proxyPort=8080

http.proxyUser=USERNAME

http.proxyPassword=PWD

```java
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", PROXY_SERVER);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", PROXY_PORT.toString());
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", PROXY_SERVER);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", PROXY_PORT.toString());
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", PROXY_USER);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", PROXY_PASSWORD);
System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true");
// AUTENTICAMOS EL PROXY
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        if (getRequestorType() == RequestorType.PROXY) {
            String prot = getRequestingProtocol().toLowerCase();
            String host = System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyHost", PROXY_SERVER);
            String port = System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyPort",PROXY_PORT.toString());
            String user = System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyUser", PROXY_USER);
            String password = System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyPassword", PROXY_PASSWORD);
            if (getRequestingHost().equalsIgnoreCase(host)) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(port) == getRequestingPort()) {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

I need this authentication to run automatically.

EDIT: This proxy should be used by a 3rd party class. If i create a new connection to a random URL like google.com, and then make a request with the 3rd party class, it works properly, so I assume that it is not using the Authenticator.setDefault. Any ideas of what is happening?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to make it work without providing the credentials via browser. Why isn't tomcat using the setProperty values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly there is a bug with the 3rd party class.
Closed